# BeanUtils.copyProperties() throw NullPointerException when using on Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, nullpointerexception, apache-commons-beanutils

`BeanUtils.copyProperties()` throw `NullPointerException` on Tomcat, but on localhost it works fine.

I've checked everything and `dto` isn't `null`, only the properties of user is `null` which is fine.

```
public void saveUser(UserDTO dto) {
    User user = new User();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(dto, user);

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

my User.java

```
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    private String encryptedPassword;
    private String salt;
    private String token;

... getters and setters method ...
}
```

Comment: You should post your User class and tell us which fields are null

Comment: my spidey senses tell me to look in the getters and setters of both of those objects. But this is just guessing. We need more info

Answer (score 0):

The error is when BeanUtils try to copy `Role role` from your `User` class

```
private Role role;
```

It will try to get properties of `Role` (via reflection) but because your `role` is `null`, it throw NPE

Use this method to ignore field `role` while copying:

```
public static void copyProperties(Object source,
                              Object target,
                              String... ignoreProperties)
```